# TypeScript error appears after compilation but has no error before compilation

Tags: typescript

So I'm learning typescript and below is my code:

```html
const sumNumberMamaMia= (a: number, b: number) => {
    return a + b
}
```

at the time before I compiled the file with this command -> tsc index.ts it has no error
However, after I compiled this file and got this index.js code below as output

```html
var sumNumberMamaMia = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

the index.ts file suddenly have error

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'sumNumberMamaMia'.ts(2451)
> index.js(1, 5): 'sumNumberMamaMia' was also declared here.

Why is that? I'm using Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

By what your error says, it looks like you declared your function **twice**. By changing its name to something else you should be able to fix the problem.

Comment: no I'm not declaring it twice, my index.ts file just contain the line of codes above I mentioned in the first code snippet. Before I compile ts file to js it has no error but after the compiled file appear which is index.js, the file index.ts more specifically, has an error appear saying the function already declared in .js file (the output file)

Comment: I also tried to change function name but after compiling the error appear again. even I tried sumNumber2158901251051290 name it still shows error after compilation (after index.js) appear

Answer (score 0):

So I just fixed it with adding export = {} at the top of the file.

The reason is, typescript consider a file that has no import or export statement as a script and have global scope so the function that I've written in typescript overlap with the generated .js file (I wonder why typescript compiler consider function from the source .ts file where the function inside generated .js file generated from as redeclaration after compiling done ?)

But by adding import = {} at the top of the file which has no import or export statement typescript considers it as module therefore block scoped.